# how can i convert char datetime values into timestamp or date format in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have data like this:

```
field    datatype    values
-----    --------    -----------------
datet    char(30)    2/8/2012 05:45 PM        
datet    char(30)    2/9/2012 05:45 PM
```

Comment: Have you treid the documentation - [`TO_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions203.htm#i1003589) or [`TO_TIMESTAMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions213.htm#i999843)?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean ?

```
SELECT TO_DATE(datet, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi PM')
FROM your_table_name;
```

(assuming 2 is the day and 8/9 are the months, otherwise change to mm/dd/yyyy)